# How to use GC in Docker Registry without accessing container

Tags: docker, garbage-collection, docker-registry

I want to use the garbage collection of the docker registry without going inside my container. Is there a way to use the API to perform the GC?
My main goal is to run the GC from a script on another server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Running garbage collection](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/garbage-collection.md#running-garbage-collection)" does not involve any remote/REST API
(although this is debated on [issue 1515](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1515)).

```
bin/registry garbage-collect [--dry-run] /path/to/config.yml
```

So you would need to add to your registry container a listener in order for you to call that remote url, and for that listener to trigger internally the gc.

Comment: Thanks, that's the information I needed. I will investigate it.